# Default timeout for driver navigation methods and ideal situation to use pageLoadTimeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

If I use -

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(url);
```

and if page is not loaded within 5 seconds, it throws timeout error.

But if I use following -

```
driver.get(url);
```

then no further command is executed until url is completely loaded. i.e. it waits for page to load completely.(This is my observation)

Based on above I've two questions -

1. What is default page load timeout for `get`, `navigate().refresh()`, `navigate().back()`, `navigate().forward()`
2. If WebDriver waits indefinitely(by default) for page load then what is the ideal situation when `pageLoadTimeout` should be used?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no default timeout. The webdriver will wait indefinitely unless specified otherwise. (Unless you're using a remote webdriver, in which case the default timeout for the node is 5 minutes. Meaning the hub will disconnect the node after 5 minutes of the last received action. You can read about it [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2).
2. You should use page load timeout when the page should load after a set period of time, as defined by the product's document and/or whoever is in-charge of the project. It varies in different projects/products, but in one 30 seconds of load can be considered a bug and in another 3 minutes, so depends on what you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. What is default page load timeout for get, navigate().refresh(), navigate().back(), navigate().forward()

As per the documentation and the description given in the Webdriver source code, there seems to be no timeout duration specified. Below is the description of `driver.get()` and `navigate().to()`. If you see [**this**](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/8677/11513) answer posted on SQA Stackexchange, apparently the default time-out is 30 minutes. As per the [documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html):

> Load a new web page in the current browser window. This is done using
>   an HTTP GET operation, and the method will block until the load is
>   complete. This will follow redirects issued either by the server or as
>   a meta-redirect from within the returned HTML. **Should a meta-redirect
>   "rest" for any duration of time, it is best to wait until this timeout
>   is over**, since should the underlying page change whilst your test is
>   executing the results of future calls against this interface will be
>   against the freshly loaded page. Synonym for
>   WebDriver.Navigation.to(String).

Question:

> 2. If WebDriver waits indefinitely(by default) for page load then what is the ideal situation when pageLoadTimeout should be used?

From [**this**](http://pageLoadTimeout) question posted on SQA Stackexchange site, `pageLoadTimeout` seems to work only on `driver.get()` and is not applicable for page loads that happen after clicking buttons/links.

Hope this information helps!